# Rails form_for direct to index action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form_for tag that I want to use the index action in the search_results controller.

My tag looks like the following.

```
<%=form_for(:search_results, url:{controller: :search_results, action: :index}, html:{id:"quickSearch"}) do | f| %>
...form fields...
<% end %>
```

However when I try to enter something into my form and submit it, it is going to the create action instead of the index action? Normally this would make sense if I didn't specify the action, but I did. I also tried removing the action and making the tag use the get method but it never hits the controller and I need it to do that.

Comment: you should user form_tag if only want to search, also in form_for add method type as well.  method:'get' so it would go to index action instead of create

Comment: So a couple of things were going on. I had search_results as a resource so every time I did a post it would automatically go to create, i could not do a get because it never hit the search_results controller. 

I ended up having to make a custom route that took me to the search_results#index via post and as you suggested use the form_tag instead.